# Swift : How to create a dictionary dynamically from a json?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, optimization, alamofire

I'd like some advice from you. I would like to create a `dictionary` from a dynamic response fetch from an API and send that dictionary in an `Alamofire` POST request.

From what I have so far it's working but I'm not satisfied with what i've made and I think the code is really messy.

**Here is an example of what I can receive**

```
"content": {
    "type": "form",
    "fields": [
        {
            "type": "select",
            "label": "Do you have your documents?",
            "field": "user.has_docs",
            "default": 0,
            "choices": [
                {
                    "value": 0,
                    "name": "Not yet"
                },
                {
                    "value": 1,
                    "name": "I do"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "input",
            "field": "user.date",
            "label": "When do you arrive?",
        }
   ]
}
```

After parsing the json with the `Codable` protocol, I have all my data in the Model `Field`

- type: String
- label: String
- field: String
- defaultValue: Int?
- choice: [Choice]?

`Choice`

- value: Int
- name: String

So I want to create my dictionary and I want the following scheme :

```
{
  "value": {
    "user": {
      "has_docs": 1,
      "date": "29/07/2020"
    }
  }
}
```

The key named : "value" is always the same value, but the other one depends of the result from the API. the prefix of the field corresponding of "parent object" and the right part is the child.

Hard coding a dictionary in Swift is not that hard, I would do

```
let dict = [
    "value": [
        "user": [
            "has_docs": 1,
            "date": "29/07/2020"
        ]
    ]
]
```

But the troubles begin, at the attempt of creating a dictionary dynamically. Values inside *user* keep only the last one and replacing *has_docs* with *date*.

I have found a workaround with using `flatmap` and `reduce` but it only allows the type [String: String], unfortunately I need to write [String: Int] too in the dictionary.

here is a sample of the code

```
let flattenedDictionary = [key : dictionaries
   .flatMap { $0 }
   .reduce([String:String]()) { (dict, tuple) in
       var nextDict = dict
       nextDict.updateValue(tuple.1 as! String, forKey: tuple.0)
       return nextDict
   }]
parameters["value"] = flattenedDictionary
```

Here :
key = "user".
dictionaries = [["has_docs": 1], ["date": "29/07/2020"]]

**Feel free to exchange if you need more informations**

If you have any clue on how you could helping me, I'll highly appreciate, thanks for reading so far.

I hope I was very understandable.

## Edit

From a general view : I'd like to create a dictionary dynamically
`[String: [String: [String: Any]]]`

Comment: I don't follow how the first JSON and the `Field` model is related to the second `value`/`user`/`has_docs` JSON... can you clarify how the two are related?

Comment: Sure, the ```Field``` is what I parse from the first JSON and it allows me to use those value. About the second JSON, this is what I'll send in an ```Alamofire``` request. So, the ```value``` key never change. Because the first JSON has a ```field``` key, I get the prefix, that's how I have the ```user``` and the ```field``` suffix (```has_docs```) is inside ```user```. That's how it is related,

Comment: I see. So the question isn't at all about the first JSON. You just want to create a dictionary dynamically based on something (doesn't matter for the purposes of this question what that something is), correct? And is this Dictionary supposed to be `[String: [String: [String: Any]]]`?

Comment: Yes exactly ! Let me edit the post

Comment: So, what's the issue with creating it? (and actually, is it `[String: String: [String:Any]]]` or one level less: `[String: [String: Any]]`, as your static code seem to imply)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit unclear if you have a `[String: [String: [String: Any]]]` or `[String: [String: Any]]` dictionary, but the concept of creating it dynamically would be rather similar.

```
var user: [String: Any] = [:]
user["has_docs"] = 1
user["date"] = Date()

let dict = ["value": user]
```

Comment: To solve my problem, I just passed from [String: [String: [String: Any]]] to [String: [String: Any]]. The first one deleted all the value of my nested dictionaries. Thank you, it helped me to refactor my code.